# pic33 pointer to a bit object

Tags: pointers, pic

I have a project on a microchip PIC33E512MU810 and I would like to set a pointer to the address of a bit object.
Something like that:

```
bool *pointer1 = &LATGbits.LATG12;
```

I know this is not allowed in microchip's compiler as per the doc, I even tried and it popped an error obviously.

> It is not possible to declare a pointer to bit types or assign the address of a bit object
> to any pointer. Nor is it possible to statically initialize bit variables so they must be
> assigned any non-zero starting value (i.e., 1) in the code itself. Bit objects will be
> cleared on startup, unless the bit is qualified persistent.

I want to know if there are some ways around that to achieve the same thing?

Thank you

Comment: How were you planning to use that pointer if it was possible? You probably need some kind of custom *struct* design. If it was C++, I would suggest a class that mimics pointers. Unfortunately, there is no C++ compiler available for 16-bit PICs AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, I have multiple struct pointer that point to struct variables.  One of the element I want it to be a bool pointer that points to a LATGbits.  So everytime I use my functions with that struct pointer as parameter I don't have to make a lot of code to know which LAT to use because it would be in the struct pointer

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is not possible. But you can harness the power of C's macros. I am not sure if this solves your exact problem. But perhaps gives you an idea at least. See below for the sample code that I have written and tested in MPLABX simulator and worked well. If it helps to resolve your problem then you can modify some definitons for your 32 bit system since I tested it for 8 bit system. In this code the `setBit` and `clearBit` macros do the trick. Here is the code:

```c
#include <xc.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Macros for setting bits in C style
#define setBit(reg, bit) reg |= 1 << bit
#define clearBit(reg, bit) reg &= ~(1 << bit)

typedef struct {
    int var1;
    char var2;
    /* Holds a reference to any SFR register change the type to uint32_t
    * if your system is 32 bit. I tested it for 8 bit in simulator*/
    volatile uint8_t *latReg; 
    char bitno; // Holds bit number
} mixedTypes_t;

void initMyMixedTypes(
            mixedTypes_t *mixedtype,
            int v1, char v2, volatile uint8_t *preg, char bitno) {
    mixedtype->var1 = v1;
    mixedtype->var2 = v2;
    mixedtype->latReg = preg;
    mixedtype->bitno = bitno;
}

// A sample function that take a sample action according to structure's var1
void makeSomething(mixedTypes_t *mtype) {
    if(mtype == NULL) return; // Make nothing if null
    if(mtype->var1 > 100) {
        setBit(*(mtype->latReg), mtype->bitno);
    }
    else {
        clearBit(*(mtype->latReg), mtype->bitno);
    }
}

void main(void) {
    
    mixedTypes_t aMixedType; // Declare your struct
    
    // Here you init your struct
    initMyMixedTypes(&aMixedType, 500, 'k', &LATA, _LATA_LA3_POSN);

    while(1) {
        setBit(LATA, 0);
        clearBit(LATA, 0);
        
        // Make something with the structure by calling some function
        makeSomething(&aMixedType); 
        
        aMixedType.var1 = 58; // Set it to a value less than 100
        
        // Now the function will evaluate again and clear the associated bit
        makeSomething(&aMixedType);
        
    }

    // Never reach here
    return;
}
```

Ask me for any part if you get confused.